# Вложенный роутинг vue router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

Пишу сайти на nuxt.js.
Столкнулся с с ошибкой:

```
Error: Avoided redundant navigation to current location:/brest
    at createRouterError (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2060)
    at createNavigationDuplicatedError (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2033)
    at HTML5History.confirmTransition (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2182)
    at HTML5History.transitionTo (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2123)
    at HTML5History.replace (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2491)
    at eval (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2913)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at VueRouter.replace (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2912)
    at VueComponent.selectCategory (categories.vue?b8d8:259)
    at eval (categories.vue?b8d8:167)
```

Имеем одну страницу, при клике на разные кнопки меняется url (через команду `$router.push`).
Получается на разные пути один компонент. Примеры путей:

```
/:region
/:region/restuarants/category/:alias
```

Код

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

import Home from './pages/Home.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export function createRouter() {
  return new Router({
    mode: 'history',
       routes: [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: '/:region',
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: '/:region/restaurants/category/:alias',
    component: Home,
  }
]
  })
}
```

Нужна Ваша помощь

Comment: В наксте роутинг по дефолту идет, если ничего в конфиге не трогать, почитайте документацию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильные вложенные роутеры будут выглядеть вот таким образом:

```js
return new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [{
      path: '/',
      component: Home,
    },
    {
      path: '/:region',
      component: Home,
      children: [{
        path: '/restaurants',
        children: [{
          path: '/category',
          children: [{
            path: '/:alias',
            name: 'region.restaurants.category.alias',
            component: RestaurantsCategoryAliasComponent
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }
  ]
})
```

А ещё лучше, создать отдельные файлы для разных груп и после их объеденить в одну как `routes`